# Collision with Ellipse

Tags: geometry, collision, ellipse

For an *elliptical billiard-table*, how can a collision be detected and resolved between the *boundary of this table* and one *billiard-ball*?

1.) I want to see if the position, P(x,y), of the billiard-ball lies

- *inside*
- *on*
- or *outside* the boundary of the ellipse. **[update: part 1. is solved]**

2.) If it lies *on* or *outside* the boundary, the new velocity has to be calculated (just flipping the velocity is not enough).

3.) If it lies *outside*, it has to be *moved back* to lie on the boundary first.

```
            ========
        ====      * ====
    ====                ====
    =                      =
    ====                ====
        ====        ====
            ========
```

Given is the position P(x,y) and the velocity V(x,y) of the billiard ball, plus the position of the center of the ellipse C(x_0,y_0) and both semi-axes a,b of the ellipse.

Comment: As much as I like solving problems like these, do you plan to code the solution?

Comment: Also, do you just want to see if P(x,y) lies on the boundary of the ellipse?

Comment: I edited my question to include more detail. I already did it for a circle, but I just can't seem to find the right start for the ellipse.

Answer (score 2):

Just use the equation of the ellipse like you used the equation for the circle:

```
((p.x-x0)/a)^2 + ((p.y-y0)/b)^2 = k
```

If k <  1 -> inside the ellipse

If k == 1 -> on the ellipse

If k >  1 -> outside the ellipse

Comment: Don't know why I didn't see that, thx! Now the less pleasant part: If the ball is outside the ellipse, it needs to be set back to the corresponding point on the boundary of the ellipse (i.e. ball managed to escape inbetween two frames). Furthermore, I just noticed that just flipping the velocity is not enough. Instead I need to calculate the new velocity?

Comment: Did you mean "If k==1 -> on the ellipse"?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are considering an elliptical (thus convex) board, I suppose you could use something based on [GJK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gilbert%E2%80%93Johnson%E2%80%93Keerthi_distance_algorithm). You would get the point of contact and a surface normal during a collision, and the minimum distance between the objects and the associated witness points if there is no collision.

Collision detection with GJK is very fast and you could implement it for other shapes very easily (you only need to recode the [support function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_function)). For an ellipse, I think the support function would be something like this (try to verify that) :

h=((x^2)/(a^4)+(y^2)/(b^4))^(-1/2)

**Some links :**

- [the initial paper GJK](http://www.win.tue.nl/~gino/solid/jgt98convex.pdf)

Comment: Thank you, but I want to find my own solution (with some help).

Answer (score 0):

Some funny experiments with elliptic table. Delphi code (without error handling!).

```
//calculates next ball position in ellipse
//ellipse semiaxes A, B, A2 = A * A, B2 = B * B
//center CX, CY
//PX,PY - old position, VX,VY - velocity components
//V - scalar velocity V = Sqrt(VX * Vx + VY * VY)

procedure TForm1.Calc;
var
  t: Double;
  eqA, eqB, eqC, DD: Double;
  EX, EY, DX, DY, FX, FY: Double;
begin
  //new position
  NPX := PX + VX;
  NPY := PY + VY;

  //if new position is outside
  if (B2 * Sqr(NPX) + A2 * Sqr(NPY) >= A2 * B2) then begin

    //find intersection point of the ray in parametric form and ellipse
    eqA := B2 * VX * VX + A2 * VY * VY;
    eqB := 2 * (B2 * PX * VX + A2 * PY * VY);
    eqC := -A2 * B2 + B2 * PX * PX + A2 * PY * PY;
    DD := eqB * eqB - 4 * eqA * eqC;
    DD := Sqrt(DD);

    //we need only one bigger root
    t := 0.5 * (DD - eqB) / eqA;

    //intersection point
    EX := PX + t * VX;
    EY := PY + t * VY;

  //mark intersection position by little circle
    Canvas.Ellipse(Round(EX - 2 + CX), Round(EY - 2 + CY),
                   Round(EX + 3 + CX), Round(EY + 3 + CY));

    //ellipse normal direction
    DX := B2 * EX;
    DY := A2 * EY;
    DD := 1.0 / (DY * DY + DX * DX);

    //helper point, projection onto the normal
    FX := DD * (NPX * DX * DX + EX * DY * DY - DY * DX * EY + DX * DY * NPY);
    FY := DD * (-DX * DY * EX + DX * DX * EY + DX * NPX * DY + DY * DY * NPY);

    //mirrored point
    NPX := NPX + 2 * (EX - FX);
    NPY := NPY + 2 * (EY - FY);

    //new velocity components
    DD := V / Hypot(NPX - EX, NPY - EY);
    VX := (NPX - EX) * DD;
    VY := (NPY - EY) * DD;
  end;

  //new position
  PX := NPX;
  PY := NPY;

  //mark new position
  Canvas.Ellipse(Round(PX - 1 + CX), Round(PY - 1 + CY),
                 Round(PX + 1 + CX), Round(PY + 1 + CY));

end;
```

[image]

A = 125, B = 100
Start from ellipse center (left picture) and from the right focus point (right picture), ball reaches left focus, then returns to right focus